# Different app.configs for different projects in same folder

Tags: .net, msbuild, app-config

I have few `*.csproj` (new format) in one folder ("same" project, different builds - no it doesn't work with single one) and I need to have `app.config` file with `bindingRedirect` for some projects. Is there a way to have distinct `app.config` names per project like it was possible for i.e. `packages.config` with `packages.<project name>.config`?

The only, fairly lame, solution I can think of as a workaround is to have a pre-build and post-build task to put the file there and remove it and make sure two builds are running together.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean exactly with *have distinct app.config names* (different files maybe?), but if you set the `$(AppConfig)` property it will use that as the filename instead of the standard app.config file. So you could e.g. set it to `app.$(MSBuildProjectName).config`. Again, not 100% sure if that is what you want? (sidenote regearding the 'same project, different builds': there nearly always a way to get that working, but I've seen *many* cases where that way was not found just due to lack of msbuild knowledge - not saying this is the case here, but just FYI)

Comment: Awesome. That's exactly what I need. I completely missed the `$(AppConfig)` property. If you add this as an answer, I'll accept it immediately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the build output you can see a target named _CopyAppConfigFile which takes care of copying the config file. Looking further in Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets it can be seen that by default msbuild uses [app.config](https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/blob/master/src/Tasks/FindAppConfigFile.cs), and this can be overridden by declaring a property `AppConfig`. So if you want to incorporate the project name in that use

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <AppConfig>app.$(MSBuildProjectName).config</AppConfig>
</PropertyGroup>
```